# Conditionally print titles in SAS?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to display different titles for different variables that go through my macro.

```
%macro mplot(dsn,vn);
title1 'hey!';
%if "&vn"="" %then title2 "Ooos" justify=left;
%else title2 "Ooos &vn" justify=left;
title3 "this line";
%mend mplot;

%mplot(_avg);
%mplot(_avgs1,s1);
```

Ideal titles are:

```
hey!
Ooos
this line

hey!
Ooos s1
this line
```

But the output is

```
hey!
Ooos
title3 this line

hey!
Ooos s1
title3 this line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by adding a semicolon after it.

```
%macro mplot(dsn,vn);
title1 'hey!';
%if "&vn"="" %then title2 "Ooos" justify=left;
%else title2 "Ooos &vn" justify=left;;
title3 "this line";
%mend mplot;
```

But I don't understand why an extra semocolon is needed.

Comment: Perhaps some code you submitted earlier was missing a semicolon, and this finally allowed your SAS session to 'catch up' on semi-colons.

Comment: The "extra" semicolon is needed to end the title statement.  The %IF statement ends with a semicolon.  The %else statement ends with a semicolon.  When the macro executes, it will generate title2 "Ooos" without a semicolon to end the title statement.  The extra semicolon ends the title statement.

Comment: Semicolons cause less confusion if you add extra %do; - %end; pears: `%if "&vn"="" %then %do;` 
`title2 "Ooos" justify=left;` 
`%end;`
`%else %do;` 
`title2 "Ooos &vn" justify=left;` 
`%end;`